# Missing method .ctor in assembly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have seen the other question and found no suitable answers so with I will ask for myself.

I created a plugin for my project to handle the saving and loading of character personalities to be used in conjunction with my AI for probabilities of actions.

the code for it is below

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Biophase.AIP
{
    public class AIP
    {
        public List<AIPersonality> Load(string path) {
            List<AIPersonality> aip = new List<AIPersonality> ();
            string file = File.ReadAllText (path);
            string[] lines = file.Split (new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (string line in lines) {
                string[] x = line.Split (':');
                aip.Add (new AIPersonality (x [0].Trim (), float.Parse (x [1].Trim ())));
            }
            return aip;
        }

        public void Save(string path, List<AIPersonality> personality) {
            string file = "";
            foreach (AIPersonality item in personality) {
                string title = item.Title;
                string content = item.Content.ToString ();
                file = file + title + " : " + content + "\n";
            }
            File.WriteAllText (path, file);
        }
    }

    public class AIPersonality
    {
        public string Title;
        public float Content;

        public AIPersonality(string title, float content) {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Content = content;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find any questions regarding this error that have answers and if they do have answers they have been too vague/too specific to be helpful in my situation. Is there something important I am missing?

the complete Error message is

> Missing method .ctor in assembly C:\Users\Joel\Documents\Tests\Sci-UI\Assets\Biophase.AIP.dll, type System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute
>   The class System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute could not be loaded, used in Biophase.AIP
>   Can't find custom attr constructor image: C:\Users\Joel\Documents\Tests\Sci-UI\Assets\Biophase.AIP.dll mtoken: 0x0a000001

the script which makes use of my AIP is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Biophase.AIP;

[System.Serializable]
public class Personality {
    [Range(0,1)]public float aggression;
    [Range(0,1)]public float cleanliness;
    [Range(0,1)]public float instigation;
    public Skills Skills;
    public Personality() {
        this.aggression = 0.5f;
        this.cleanliness = 0.5f;
        this.instigation = 0.5f;
    }
    public void Randomize() {
        this.aggression = Rand ();
        this.cleanliness = Rand ();
        this.instigation = Rand ();
        this.Skills.Randomize ();
    }
    private float Rand() {
        return float.Parse (Random.Range (0.0f, 1.0f).ToString ("F2"));
    }
    public void Save(string path) {
        AIP aip = new AIP ();
        List<AIPersonality> aaip = new List<AIPersonality> ();
        aaip.Add (new AIPersonality ("aggression", this.aggression));
        aaip.Add (new AIPersonality ("cleanliness", this.cleanliness));
        aaip.Add (new AIPersonality ("instigation", this.instigation));
        aaip.Add (new AIPersonality ("magic", this.Skills.Magic));
        aaip.Add (new AIPersonality ("tech", this.Skills.Tech));
        aaip.Add (new AIPersonality ("rangedWeaponry", this.Skills.RangedWeaponry));
        aaip.Add (new AIPersonality ("bluntWeaponry", this.Skills.BluntWeaponry));
        aaip.Add (new AIPersonality ("sharpWeaponry", this.Skills.SharpWeaponry));
        aaip.Add (new AIPersonality ("speech", this.Skills.Speech));
        aip.Save (path, aaip);
    }

    public void Load(string path) {
        AIP aip = new AIP ();
        List<AIPersonality> aipp = aip.Load (path);
        foreach (AIPersonality ai in aipp) {
            if (ai.Title == "aggression") {
                this.aggression = ai.Content;
            } else if (ai.Title == "cleanliness") {
                this.cleanliness = ai.Content;
            } else if (ai.Title == "instigation") {
                this.instigation = ai.Content;
            } else if (ai.Title == "magic") {
                this.Skills.Magic = ai.Content;
            } else if (ai.Title == "tech") {
                this.Skills.Tech = ai.Content;
            } else if (ai.Title == "rangedWeaponry") {
                this.Skills.RangedWeaponry = ai.Content;
            } else if (ai.Title == "bluntWeaponry") {
                this.Skills.BluntWeaponry = ai.Content;
            } else if (ai.Title == "sharpWeaponry") {
                this.Skills.SharpWeaponry = ai.Content;
            } else if (ai.Title == "speech") {
                this.Skills.Speech = ai.Content;
            }
        }
    }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Skills {
    [Range(0,1)]public float Magic;
    [Range(0,1)]public float Tech;
    [Range(0,1)]public float RangedWeaponry;
    [Range(0,1)]public float BluntWeaponry;
    [Range(0,1)]public float SharpWeaponry;
    [Range(0,1)]public float Speech;
    public Skills() {
        this.BluntWeaponry = 0.5f;
        this.Magic = 0.5f;
        this.RangedWeaponry = 0.5f;
        this.SharpWeaponry = 0.5f;
        this.Speech = 0.5f;
        this.Tech = 0.5f;
    }
    public void Randomize() {
        this.BluntWeaponry = Rand ();
        this.Magic = Rand ();
        this.RangedWeaponry = Rand ();
        this.SharpWeaponry = Rand ();
        this.Speech = Rand ();
        this.Tech = Rand ();
    }

    private float Rand() {
        return float.Parse (Random.Range (0.0f, 1.0f).ToString ("F2"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you define public AIP() in class and then try

Comment: I have attempted that, it was my first attempt, I took it out because it was empty. which I thought was my problem

Comment: which line gives exception ?

Comment: it doesn't say which line

Comment: it may be related to dll version or framework, but Im not sure

Comment: I just recently wrote the files in question and files that I wrote not too long ago work just fine. I have added the script which uses this class

Answer (score 0):

The naming (AIP in class and namespace) could be making weird relations. Try changing one of them.

```
namespace Biophase.AIP
    {
        public class AIP
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove next construction in dll:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

And rebuild your .dll in new version MonoDevelop.

Comment: I tested a variety of ideas including a blank file and i was still getting the error. The error is generating from within the second script

Comment: Can try to access the data stored in the dll directly?

Comment: Instead AIP aip = new AIP (); use Biophase.AIP.AIP aip = new Biophase.AIP.AIP ();

Comment: how would I access the data directly? and I did attempt your other suggestions and nothings working. I'm beginning to think that I can't create a dll for saving a file.

Comment: Dll created in MonoDevelop?

Comment: Yes, it was created in MonoDevelop.

Comment: Quick note, I had previously created DLL files that worked, and now even they are generating the same error, maybe something is off with my Unity settings, not that I can think of what I've changed.